# What does "central value" mean?

Tags: statistics

How to calculate central value of the following sets:
I'm thinking is the same as the median - is it?

$\{-2, -1, 3, 5, 7 , 1, 3 , 6, 2 , -1, -5\}$ and 
$\{-2, -1, 3, 5, 7 , 1, 3 , 6, 2 , -1 \}$

Comment: Probably the median. *What else can it be?*

Answer (score 2):

The term "central value" is ambiguous. [This link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_tendency) may help, but without some other information, there's no way to know whether you're supposed to find the arithmetic mean, median, mode, or some other measure of central tendency.

---

[**Arithmetic Mean**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean)

This is what people most frequently mean when they say "average." You can calculate the arithmetic mean of a collection of numbers by dividing their sum by the number of numbers. For the set $\left\{ -2, -1, 3, 5, 7 , 1, 3 , 6, 2 , -1, -5\right\}$, the sum is $18$ and there are $11$ elements, so the average is $$\frac{18}{11} \approx 1.636$$

For the set $\left\{ -2, -1, 3, 5, 7 , 1, 3 , 6, 2 , -1 \right\}$, the sum is $23$ and there are $10$ numbers, so the average is $$\frac{23}{10} = 2.3$$

---

[**Median**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median)

Intuitively, this is the "middle" number of a set of numbers, if they are put in increasing (or decreasing) order. The median of set $\{-2, -1, 3, 5, 7 , 1, 3 , 6, 2 , -1, -5\}$ is $2$. The median of the set $\{-2, -1, 3, 5, 7 , 1, 3 , 6, 2 , -1\}$ is between $2$ and $3$, so it is equal to $$\frac{2+3}{2}=2.5$$

---

[**Mode**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_%28statistics%29)

This is simply the most frequently occurring number, or, in the case of a tie, there can be more than one mode. Both of your sets have two modes: $3$ and $-1$.